# Resetear campo Img HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Cordial Saludo,

Espero se encuentren bien y me puedan ayudar con lo que deseo hacer.

Les comento lo que hago hasta el momento.

Tengo un input file.que lo que hace es cargar una imagen y al lado aparece la preview de la imagen que fue cargada.

Hasta acá vamos bien.

Una vez que tengo el preview de la imagen, tengo otro boton para resetear eso.

El caso es que logró limpiar el input, pero la imagen sigue ahí..

No se como hacer que se quite, pero que al momento de escoger otra imagen siga funcionando el preview.

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 400px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {    
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).load(function(){

 $(function() {
  $('#file-input').change(function(e) {
      addImage(e); 
     });

     function addImage(e){
      var file = e.target.files[0],
      imageType = /image.*/;

      if (!file.type.match(imageType))
       return;

      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = fileOnload;
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
     }

     function fileOnload(e) {
      var result=e.target.result;
      $('#imgSalida').attr("src",result);

     }
    });
  });

</script>

<form id="frm-example" name="frm-example">
   <input name="file-input" id="file-input" type="file" />
   <br />
    <div id="limpiarimg">
   <img id="imgSalida" style="width:100%;max-width:300px" src=""/>
   <div id="myModal2" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img012">
  <div id="caption2"></div>
</div>
</div>
 </form>

  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>



    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>





      <button id="btn-example-file-reset" type="button">Reset file</button>



<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#btn-example-file-reset').on('click', function(e){
   var $el = $('#file-input');
   $el.wrap('<form>').closest('form').get(0).reset();
   $el.unwrap();

});
</script>




<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal2');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('imgSalida');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img012");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption2");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Gracias y espero me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en esta parte del código:

```
$('#btn-example-file-reset').on('click', function(e){
  var $el = $('#file-input');
  $el.wrap('<form>').closest('form').get(0).reset();
  $el.unwrap();
});
```

En esta función falta vaciar la imagen. Vacías el `input` pero la imagen que has mostrado no va ligada a él, estas recogiéndola y mostrándola pero el `source` (`src`) de dicha imagen se mantiene aunque desaparezca del `input`. 
Debería ser de la siguiente manera:

```
$('#btn-example-file-reset').on('click', function(e){
   var $el = $('#file-input');
   $el.wrap('<form>').closest('form').get(0).reset();
   $el.unwrap();

   $("img#imgSalida")[0].setAttribute("src", "");
 });
```

Con:

```
$("img#imgSalida")[0].setAttribute("src", "");
```

Lo que se hace es reiniciar el atributo `src` de la imagen a una cadena vacía.

Te dejo el código corregido. Te recomiendo que los scripts que inicializas (la librería de `jquery` y la llamada a `js/index.js`) lo hagas dentro del `head`, para que se carguen lo primero y te evites problemas luego.

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  $(function() {
    $('#file-input').change(function(e) {
      addImage(e); 
    });

    function addImage(e){
      var file = e.target.files[0],
      imageType = /image.*/;

      if (!file.type.match(imageType))
        return;

      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = fileOnload;
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    function fileOnload(e) {
      var result=e.target.result;
      $('#imgSalida').attr("src",result);
    }
  });
}); 


$('#btn-example-file-reset').on('click', function(e){
  var $el = $('#file-input');
  $el.wrap('<form>').closest('form').get(0).reset();
  $el.unwrap();
  
  $("img#imgSalida")[0].setAttribute("src", "");
});

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal2');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('imgSalida');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img012");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption2");

img.onclick = function(){
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 400px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {    
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="frm-example" name="frm-example">
      <input name="file-input" id="file-input" type="file" />
      <br />
      <div id="limpiarimg">
        <img id="imgSalida" style="width:100%;max-width:300px" src=""/>
        <div id="myModal2" class="modal">
          <span class="close">&times;</span>
          <img class="modal-content" id="img012">
          <div id="caption2"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <button id="btn-example-file-reset" type="button">Reset file</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias, Justo lo que necesitaba, Me ayudaste mucho